# Comparar fechas con moment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Estoy teniendo problemas para comparar 2 fechas con **moment.js**

Necesito saber cuando la fecha de un JWT token expiró.
La fecha del token la tengo en *timestamp* y la paso a un format ('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm') `con moment`.
Luego, obtengo la fecha del momento en el mismo formato y las comparo.

Pero se ve que no anda la comparacion porque me da false en casos donde no debería.

```js
  async verfiyExpiredToken(token:string):Promise<boolean>{
    const tokenDecoded:ITokenDecoded = jwt_decode(token);    
    const tokenExpiredDate:string = (moment.unix(tokenDecoded).utc().subtract(1, 'minutes').format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'))
    const now:string = moment().utc().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm')  

    const simulateToken     = '13-07-2022 18:35'
    const simulateNow       = '14-07-2022 18:35'

    console.log('simulateNow ES MAYOR A simulateToken?',moment(simulateNow) >= moment(simulateToken));
    
    return moment(now) >= moment(tokenExpiredDate)
  }
```

**tokenDecoded valor sin format:** 1657823773

Cree dos variables para ir probando "simulateToken" y "simulateNow", en estas, la fecha mayor es el now y sin embargo la comparacion me dice "false".

Probé también comparando el *string* directamente pero no funciona.

Comment: Tal y como te comentan, evita usar `moment`. En vez de ello usa directamente `Date` y compara los valores que devuelve el método `valueOf()` de dicho Objeto. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal como ya te han comentado, no deberías usar [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) ya que es una librería obsoleta (*deprecated*) y los autores de la misma recomiendan usar otra librería.

Si el valor de `tokenDecoded` es numérico, tal como lo dices en tu pregunta:

> **tokenDecoded valor sin format: 1657823773**

entonces compara directamente ese valor con el momento actual.

Sin embargo, debes tomar en cuenta que [la expiración de un token JWT se mide en segundos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim) y en Javascript los valores de fecha se miden en milisegundos, por lo cual, para comparar ambos instantes debes convertir los segundos en milisegundos o viceversa.

Por ejemplo, convirtiendo el valor de `tokenDecoded` en milisegundos:

```js
const tokenDecoded = 1657823773 * 1000;
const now = Date.now();

if(tokenDecoded > now) {
  console.log('Token activo');
}
else {
  console.log('Token expirado');
}

console.log(new Date(tokenDecoded));
console.log(new Date(now));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

De esta forma es sencillo comparar dichos valores ya que ambos son numéricos y están basados en Unix Epoch, por lo tanto son comparables de forma segura. [Ver documentación de `Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Gracias por comentar,me ayudo! 
Consulta, cual es la libreria que se recomienda para reemplazar a moment?

Comment: @Sunset, en la página oficial de [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/future/) mencionan que es preferible no usar librerías, aunque también ponen una [lista de opciones](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/) que te tocará revisar y analizar para ver cuál es la que mejor se adapta a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Desde hace algún tiempo no se recomienda usar moment.js y puedes leer las razones en el [estado del proyecto](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) en su sitio web oficial.

Una opción sencilla es usar [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) para convertir cadena de fecha en milisegundos transcurridos desde el 1 de enero de 1970. Quizá el único problema es que debes proporcionar la cadena en formato `yyyy-mm-dd hh:ss`, pero no es algo muy difícil de resolver.

**Edición:** Otro factor importante es que parece que el token es una fecha en segundos, transcurridos a partir del 1-ene/1970 y no es necesario convertirla, a menos que sea solo para agregar milisegundos.

Ya con eso, puedes usar los métodos del objeto [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) en lugar de la librería moment.js

```js
const simulateToken = '2022-07-13 18:35'
const simulateNow = '2022-07-14 18:35'

// Confirmar que se pudieron interpretar las fechas
console.log(Date.parse(simulateNow), Date.parse(simulateToken));

console.log('simulateNow ES MAYOR A simulateToken?', Date.parse(simulateNow) >= Date.parse(simulateToken));

// tokenDecoded valor sin formato: 1657823773 <- Son segundos
const unformat = 1657823773 * 1000; // Convertir a milisegundos
const format = new Date();
format.setTime(unformat);
console.log(format.getFullYear() + '-' + (format.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + format.getDay());
```

Sabiendo esto, puedes simplificar:

```js
// tokenDecoded valor sin formato: 1657823773 <- Son segundos
const token = 1657823773 * 1000; // Convertir a milisegundos
const now = (new Date()).getTime();
console.log('token ES MAYOR O IGUAL QUE now?', token >= now);
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el formato que puede parsear `Date.parse` varía en diferentes navegadores. Tu solución por ejemplo [no funciona](https://ibb.co/JnnW5M0) en Safari móvil.

Comment: Después de la edición sigue sin funcionar. Lo que no funciona en Safari es el constructor de Date con un String en formato `DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm`. Es preferible usar moment a una solución como esta, incluso aunque esté deprecated. La prioridad debe ser el soporte a todos los navegadores.

Comment: No sé si son ustedes mismos, pero por si acaso no entren en guerra de negativos, ambas respuestas son válidas, sólo necesitaban aclarar detalles, ninguna merece el negativo puesto y por ello yo les he puesto un positivo a ambas, me parecen respuestas correctas.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, no es necesario usar una librería, sobre todo porque el token ya es una fecha, en segundos y todo se simplifica.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, no acostumbro esas tácticas y te agradezco el interés por mantener un ambiente sin afán competitivo.

Answer (score -1):

Para comparar dos fechas en **moment** usa los métodos [`isAfter`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/03-is-after/), [`isBefore`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/01-is-before/) y [`isSame`](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/02-is-same/).

- `isAfter` se usa para saber si la fecha actual está después (es mayor) de la fecha pasada por parámetros.
- `isBefore` se usa para saber si la fecha actual está antes (es menor) de la fecha pasada por parámetros.
- `isSame` se usa para saber si la fecha actual es igual a la fecha pasada por parámetros.

Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
const format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'; 

const simulateToken = moment('13-07-2022 18:35', format)
const simulateNow   = moment('14-07-2022 18:35', format)

console.log('simulateNow ES MAYOR A simulateToken?', simulateNow.isAfter(simulateToken));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Checa [este tutorial](https://poopcode.com/compare-two-dates-in-javascript-using-moment/) para más detalles.

---

Alternativamente a **moment** que ya está descontinuado puedes usar vanilla javascript parseando el formato de tu fecha para que sea compatible con Safari:

```js
function parseDateTime(dateTime) {
  const [date, time] = dateTime.split(" ");
  const [DD, MM, YYYY] = date.split("-");
  const [h, m] = time.split(":");
  return new Date(YYYY, MM - 1, DD, h, m, 0);
}

const simulateToken = parseDateTime('13-07-2022 18:35')
const simulateNow   = parseDateTime('14-07-2022 18:35')

console.log('simulateNow ES MAYOR A simulateToken?', simulateNow.getTime() >= simulateToken.getTime());
```

Considera de manera alternativa las librerías recomendadas en la propia página de **[moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/)**:

- [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)
- [Day.js](https://day.js.org/)
- [date-fns](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/)
- [js-Joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/)

Comment: Cabe destacar que `moment` está deprecado y se desaconseja su uso. Saludos

Comment: No sé si son ustedes mismos, pero por si acaso no entren en guerra de negativos, ambas respuestas son válidas, sólo necesitaban aclarar detalles, ninguna merece el negativo puesto y por ello yo les he puesto un positivo a ambas, me parecen respuestas correctas.